# Кластеризация данных с использованием группировки

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Есть DataFrame, который содержит в себе такие данные:

```
df_scale = pd.DataFrame({"название_книги_код": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4], 
                         "век_описание": [-0.051467, -0.051467,-0.051467, -0.048411, -0.048411,
                                          -0.173312, -0.173312, -0.173312, -0.173312, -0.040507],
                         "век_название_главы": [-0.084965, -0.087059, -0.088990, -0.089571, -0.089679,
                                               -0.083948, -0.081229, -0.100679, -0.090792, 0.086691], 
                         "значение_главы": [15, 35, 50, 50, 50, 25, 25, 25, 25, 19], 
                         "век_навыки_текст": [-0.021923, -0.076697, -0.051627, -0.023046, -0.026204, 0.003370, 
                                       -0.103621, -0.002899, -0.115548, 0.026655]})
```

Необходимо кластеризировать данные так, чтобы на каждое `название_книги_код` приходился один кластер. Известно, что есть 5 кластеров. Текстовые данные я уже представил в числовом формате.

Я воспользовался простым методом KMeans:

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf.fit(df.название_книги)
text = tfidf.transform(df.навыки_текст)
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5, random_state=100).fit_predict(text)
```

но на предсказании выводится следующее:

```
in[]: kmeans
out[]: array([1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 5, 5, 4, 4])
```

Получается так, что выводом являются кластеры, которые разнятся для `название_книги_код`.
Вывод должен быть, например, такой:

```
in[]: kmeans
out[]: array([4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4])
```

Comment: А вы попробуйте порисовать графики где на одной оси `название_книги_код`, а на другой - одна из остальных фич. И вы увидите, что у вас данные очень плохо разделяются по вашей целевой фиче. Тут никакая кластеризация не справится.

Comment: Ну то есть какая-нибудь деревянная модель используя `век_описание` легко научится по вашим данным. а все методы, которые не используют целевую переменную тут ничего не добьются с такими данными.

Answer (score 0):

На первом занятии по кластеризации вам должны были рассказать, что есть данные номинальные, а есть данные числовые. Даже если вы зашифровали свои номинальные данные числами, от того они числовыми не стали. Если вы названия книг превратили в код -  это все равно не число. Его нельзя складывать, умножать, делить. Все что с ним можно делать - это сравнивать "равно-не равно".

Метод kMeans - даже из названия это видно -  строит кластеры исходя из средних значений попавших в него элементов. А что значит "среднее значение названий книг"? Бред. Про остальные ваши параметры - похоже примерно то-же самое, хотя я не понимаю, что реально представляют ваши числа.

Итак, если на вход метода, по своей сути предназначенного для работы с числовыми данными подать данные номинальные,  алгоритм честно отработает и честно на выходе выдаст бредовый результат.

Нельзя решать задачу методами, по определению не предназначенными для работы с такими данными.